# Nest.js Passport won't remember user after logging in

Tags: mysql, nestjs, passport.js, typeorm

## Problem summary

I tried for about 3 hours to resolve this issue, but I just can't setup my Nest.js app to make a working login mechanism. When I log user with api/auth/login then setted up console logs are informing that all should be working, but after trying to access api/auth/profile (ikr) then the error 401 comes up as user is not logged in. Also req.user is empty.

## Setup explanation

I'm trying to make a Passport login in Nest.js. I'm following https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport but instead of using Jwt strategy, I'm just trying to use local strategy without Jwt. Also user is logging by user id and password instead of something else. Password isn't hashed for now and I'm aware of safety precautions. No fancy additions.

## Basic code show around

Project has backend and frontend folders
Whole problem lives in backend
You can try running through the code yourself at branch `login`: https://github.com/dudematthew/hipster-tools/tree/login

Whole mechanism should revolve around those files:

### main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { TypeORMSession } from './database/entities/session.entity';
import { LoggerErrorInterceptor } from 'nestjs-pino';
import { TypeormStore } from 'connect-typeorm';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as passport from 'passport';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import 'dotenv/config';
import "reflect-metadata";

import { createAgent } from '@forestadmin/agent';
import { createSqlDataSource } from '@forestadmin/datasource-sql';

const dbC = {
  protocol: 'mysql',
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10),
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
};

const connectionString = `${dbC.protocol}://${dbC.username}:${dbC.password}@${dbC.host}:${dbC.port}/${dbC.database}`;

// console.log(dbC);
// console.log(connectionString);


async function bootstrap() {

  const forestAdminAgent = createAgent({
    authSecret: process.env.FOREST_AUTH_SECRET,
    envSecret: process.env.FOREST_ENV_SECRET,
    isProduction: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    typingsPath: './typings.ts',
    typingsMaxDepth: 5,
  });
  
  // Create your SQL datasource
  forestAdminAgent.addDataSource(createSqlDataSource(connectionString));

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: true,
  });

  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggerErrorInterceptor());

  const sessionRepository = app.get(getRepositoryToken(TypeORMSession));

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        // Max age of the cookie is 60 days
        maxAge: 60000 * 24 * 60,
      },
      store: new TypeormStore().connect(sessionRepository),
    }),
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log(`Serializing user`, user);
    done(null, user);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log(`Deserializing user`, user);
    done(null, user);
  });

  // Initialize Passport and restore authentication state
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  // Start the Forest Admin server
  await forestAdminAgent.mountOnNestJs(app).start();

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

### auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { UserModule } from "src/database/entities/user/user.module";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { AuthController } from "./auth.controller";
import { PassportModule } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { LocalStrategy } from "./strategies/local.strategy";
import { SessionSerializer } from "./session.serializer";


@Module({
    imports: [
        UserModule,
        PassportModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        LocalStrategy,
        SessionSerializer,
    ],
    controllers: [
        AuthController,
    ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

### auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { UserService } from "src/database/entities/user/user.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService,
    ) {}

    async validateUser(id: number, password: string): Promise<{}> {
        console.info(`Validating user with credentials: ${JSON.stringify({ id, password })}`);

        const user = await this.userService.findOneById(id);

        if (!user || user.password !== password)
            return null;
        
        const { password: _, ...result } = user;

        console.log(result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

### auth.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, HttpCode, HttpStatus, Inject, Post, Req, Request, UseGuards } from "@nestjs/common";
import { UserService } from "src/database/entities/user/user.service";
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from "@nestjs/cache-manager";
import { Cache } from "cache-manager";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { LocalAuthGuard } from "./guards/local-auth.guard";

@Controller('/api/auth/')
export class AuthController {

    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService,
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
        @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER)
        private readonly cacheManager: Cache,
    ) {}

    @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Post('login')
    async login(@Request() req) {
        console.log(`Logging in user: ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}`);

        await req.logIn(req.user, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
        });

        return req.user;
    }
    
    // Get user info
    @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
    @Get('profile')
    getProfile(@Request() req): string {
        console.log(`Getting profile for user: ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}`);

        return JSON.stringify(req.user, null, 4);
    }

}
```

### local.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
import { AuthService } from "../auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
    ) {
        // Call the super constructor passing in the options 
        // object containing the usernameField and passwordField
        super({
            usernameField: 'id',
        });
    }

    /**
     * Validate a user's credentials against the database
     * This method is called by Passport when attempting to authenticate a user
     * @param id user's id
     * @param password user's password
     * @returns the user if the credentials are valid
     */
    async validate(id: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        console.log(`Validating user with id: ${id} and password: ${password}`);
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(parseInt(id), password);

        if (!user)
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
    
        console.log(`User validated: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);

        return user;
    }
}
```

### local-auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

### session.serializer.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { UserService } from "src/database/entities/user/user.service";
import { PassportSerializer } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { UserEntity } from "src/database/entities/user/user.entity";

@Injectable()
export class SessionSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
    constructor (
        private userService: UserService,
    ) {
        super();
    }

    serializeUser(user: any, done: (err: Error, user: UserEntity) => void) {
        console.log(`Serializing user`, user);
        done(null, user);
    }

    async deserializeUser(user: any, done: (err: Error, user: UserEntity) => void) {
        console.log(`Deserializing user`, user);
        done(null, user);
    }

}
```

1. Tried to run the code through AI, looked through documentations, made various changes and checked many stack forums but nothing changed
2. I added user serialization that could make the user be remembered but nothing - although got new error:

```
[Nest] 6568  - 22.10.2023, 20:19:22   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'iMHjie9Uj6Faes-1vQ6zq5ydX2FSu6W9' for key 'PRIMARY'
QueryFailedError: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'iMHjie9Uj6Faes-1vQ6zq5ydX2FSu6W9' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mateusz IT\Documents\Projekty\hipster-tools\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
```

You can check the code and console.log outputs are below (idc about passwords):

```
Validating user with id: 1 and password: 123Hipster
Validating user with credentials: {"id":1,"password":"123Hipster"}
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'HipsterSavage',
  image: 'https://i.imgur.com/fwadYQ4.jpg',
  isAdmin: true,
  createdAt: 2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z
}
User validated: {"id":1,"name":"HipsterSavage","image":"https://i.imgur.com/fwadYQ4.jpg","isAdmin":true,"createdAt":"2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z","updatedAt":"2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z"}
Logging in user: {"id":1,"name":"HipsterSavage","image":"https://i.imgur.com/fwadYQ4.jpg","isAdmin":true,"createdAt":"2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z","updatedAt":"2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z"}
Serializing user {
  id: 1,
  name: 'HipsterSavage',
  image: 'https://i.imgur.com/fwadYQ4.jpg',
  isAdmin: true,
  createdAt: 2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-10-22T14:30:31.148Z
}
```